# Bootstrap: Search Icon Button Inside Input Box separates from Inputbox at non-desktop Resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fit a Search Icon Button inside the Search Input Box ( Working with Bootstrap)

While everything works fine at Desktop resolution, at non desktop resolutions when the menu items merge into a dropdown, the button and the input box go at two extremes.

Like this: http://prntscr.com/4m31c7

I've made a fiddle about the issue: http://www.bootply.com/G7TudgkXPA

What should be done that the button and the input box remain together at all times? ( also its of prime importance that the Search Box is aligned at the center: it cannot be to a left or right )

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it 100% width. that way it should reach the other element in both scenarios.

```
input#srch-term {
background: none;
border: 2px solid white;
border-top-left-radius: 1.5em;
border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5em;
  width:100%
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/TzVC7Ww2fl#

Comment: Thats good, but not what i want. at smaller dimensions, it occupies the whole width. I dont want it to stretch that much: http://prntscr.com/4m825g